# Java Coding fix for dominos

Tags: java

Given an arrangement of dominos, determine, whether or not it is a legal arrangement and return True or False accordingly. For example, this is an illegal arrangement [2 3][4 2][2 2][3 5] and this is a legal arrangement of Dominos. [2 3][3 5][5 4][4 5].

This is the coding I have right now, but I want it to output illegal when it is illegal and legal when it is legal. Is there a way to have both arrangements in the coding and out out which is the illegal one and which is the legal one?

```
public class Domino {
   private int leftValue;
   private int rightValue;

    public Domino(int leftValue, int rightValue) {
       this.leftValue = leftValue;
       this.rightValue = rightValue;
   }

   public int getLeftValue() {
       return leftValue;
   }

   public int getRightValue() {
       return rightValue;
   }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
       // This creates the Array
       Domino[] dominos = new Domino[] {
           new Domino(2, 3),
           new Domino(3, 2),
           new Domino(2, 5),
           new Domino(2, 5) 
       };
       // This part Loops and matchs left and right values
       Domino previous = null;

       for (Domino current : dominos) {
           if (previous != null) {
               if (current.getLeftValue() != previous.getRightValue()) {
                   try {
                       throw new Exception("Illegal");
                   } catch (Exception e) {
                       e.printStackTrace();
                   } 
               }
           }
           previous = current;
       }
    }
}
```

Comment: In what way doesn't your code work?

Comment: You should save the previous and next domino's in your class itself otherwise if you change to for instance a hashmap it wont have the same order.

Comment: You can create both arrangements in your main-class. E. g. `Domino[] dominosGood = new Domino[] {` and `Domino[] dominosBad = new Domino[] {`. Then you do your check for both arrangements: `for (Domino current : dominosGood) {` and `for (Domino current : dominosBad) {`.

Comment: @LuudvanKeulen If I understood you - no - why?

Comment: @Daij-Djan Really good argumentation... Care to explain why not?

Comment: And I suggest you put your test code in a separate method so you can simply call it from your main class.

Comment: @LuudvanKeulen why would a single domino now about the context it is in. you'd 'infer'/'inject' additional contexts - where IMO it doesn't belong

Comment: @Daij-Djan The domino should know his neighbour domino's. This way you can make method's inside the domino class to see if the next one is valid or not.

Comment: Thank you for all your comments you all gave me some ideas, and I figured it out. Thanks again.

Comment: @LuudvanKeulen that's like assigning next to a class integer. You create bad dependancies.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try replace you `for` loop  with this one:

```
    for (Domino current : dominos) {
        if (previous != null) {
            if (current.getLeftValue() != previous.getRightValue()) {
                System.out.println("[" + previous.getLeftValue() + " " + previous.getRightValue()
                        + "][" + current.getLeftValue() + " " + current.getRightValue() + "] is illegal");
            } else {
                System.out.println("[" + previous.getLeftValue() + " " + previous.getRightValue()
                        + "][" + current.getLeftValue() + " " + current.getRightValue() + "] is legal");
            }
        }
        previous = current;
    }
```